# What are all the new HTML document types in VS 2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, html, visual-studio-2012

I just installed VS 2012 RC and in the HTML toolbar dropdown it has a bunch of new options:

- DOCTYPE: HTML5
- HTML5
- XHTML5

What's the difference between the two HTML5 options? I thought the recommendation for HTML5 was not to specify a DOCTYPE, so the first option is kinda like "would you like some caffeine with that decaf?"

I was pretty sure that W3C abandoned XHTML in favor of evolving HTML, so what's this new XHTML5 option? Update: seems like Wikipedia [had an answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML5#XHTML5) for that.

Thanks in advance!

***Update*: posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864914/why-does-vs-2012-rc-have-both-doctype-html5-and-html5-in-the-web-toolbar) for the unanswered bits.**

PS: I am not looking for an explanation of the purpose of the dropdown, but rather an explanation of what the difference is between choosing "DOCTYPE:HTML5" and "HTML5".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the HTML5 vs. DOCTYPE:HTML5 question, here's what I've observed while using VS 2012 RTM:

The DOCTYPE:{value} option tells VS to examine your page and attempt to figure out from the DOCTYPE and html tags what level of validation to apply. For example, if I create a page that begins as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

then the DOCTYPE:{value} option becomes DOCTYPE: HTML5. If, however, my page starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
```

then it becomes DOCTYPE: XHTML5.

The options that don't have the DOCTYPE: prefix force VS to use the selected level of validation regardless of what the structure/content of your page might suggest.

Comment: Awesome - this is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

XHTML 5.0, usually written XHTML5, means HTML5 in XHTML serialization. Reference: [HTML vs XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml) in the W3C HTML5 draft. So it’s HTML5 written using XML-conformant markup. Yes, the name “XHTML5” is odd and confusing, but it was probably selected for its assumed coolness factor.

All HTML5 drafts require the use of DOCTYPE preamble. See e.g. [The DOCTYPE in W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype) HTML5 draft. It’s not really a document type declaration even formally (there is no DTD for HTML5, and [my attempts at writing one](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html5-dtd.html) suggest that it would be rather problematic). Rather, it’s just a magic string that is to be used to make browsers apply “standards mode” vs. “[quirks mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)”. And it does this job well.

To see the difference between “DOCTYPE:HTML5” and “HTML5”, check out their effects on the source code of the result. My bet is that the latter mean HTML5 without DOCTYPE preamble, which is illogical, as HTML5 requires the preamble. If this is the case, “HTML5” throws browsers to “quirks mode”, which is normally bad for any new page, but often necessary for old pages if one wants to avoid major rewrite.

Comment: Where is it called XHTML 5.0? I've never seen it called that in any official documentation.

Comment: I've been using `<!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html>` and that seems to work fine. The thing is, the dropdown in VS only shows when you're editing something HTML-ish, and thus only controls how the document is validated. But I don't get why it needs two options for HTML5..

Comment: @Alohci XHTML5 is explained in the reference link. I'm still not any wiser in regards to the two HTML5 options.

Comment: @Jukka "check out their effects on the source code of the result" makes no sense. The source exists before I choose a dropdown value.

Comment: @MortenMertner - Correct. But it's always called "XHTML5" not "XHTML 5.0". 'HTML5' (i.e. without a space), was once (circa 2007) called "HTML 5" (i.e. with a space), but neither HTML5 nor XHTML5 has ever had a ".0" subversion number.

Comment: @Alohci that's a bit nitpicky, but I see your point. All this doesn't help answer the original question though.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should not have mentioned the spelling “XHTML 5.0” at all. Anyway, the remaining question is the difference between “DOCTYPE: HTML5” and “HTML5”, apparently in some validation/checking only. Testing with various simple incorrect documents might reveal this. It *sounds* a bit like “DOCTYPE: HTML5” referred to DTD-based validation.

Comment: @Jukka I wasn't looking for an answer based on assumptions (I could infer as much by guessing myself). You were correct about everything with XHTML5 though.