# Why does VS 2012 RC have both "DOCTYPE: HTML5" and "HTML5" in the web toolbar?

Tags: html, visual-studio

I just installed VS 2012 RC and in the HTML toolbar dropdown it has both of the following:

- DOCTYPE: HTML5
- HTML5

What's the difference between the two HTML5 options? I thought the recommendation for HTML5 was not to specify a DOCTYPE, so the first option is kinda like "would you like some caffeine with that decaf?"

Note: the toolbar is disabled unless you're editing an HTML page and is not used for code generation of any sort. The toolbar selection has something to do with validation of the contents of the file you're editing (be it a full page, layout or partial view), and I'm looking to find out exactly what the difference is between choosing one option or the other.

I'd also appreciate it if any answers were based on actual knowledge, rather than guesswork on what the added "DOCTYPE:" prefix could imply.

Comment: -1 If you don't want answers, then just delete the question.

Comment: @guffa: 160k with guess work? thats some going :P

Comment: Every document must need a `DOCTYPE` [Quirks Mode and Standards Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla's_Quirks_Mode)

Comment: @Guffa I'm looking for answers to my question. Posting some arbitrarily related knowledge about DOCTYPEs doesn't help me. Read the damn question before you post an answer, and don't downvote my question just because I don't happen to not like your non-answer to it. Kindly remove the downvote instead of being an ass.

Comment: Why do you think that I didn't read the question? Read the damn answer before you say that it's not good enough. I'm not removing the downvote because you deserve it. You think that I am an ass? Consider how you treat people who are just trying to help you, and consider how eager they will be to help you in the future.

Comment: @Guffa You stated, in your own answer, that you didn't know the difference between the two options. I already know what a DOCTYPE is and whatever else you said, true as it may be, was not an answer to the question. I don't see how you can fault me, as I specifically mention in the question that I'm not looking for clever guesses. In fact, I added the last paragraph precisely to avoid the kind of answer you provided. So pretty please, remove the downvote so I have a chance of someone with a real answer chiming in.

Comment: @Guffa Well, at least someone appreciates that there is a real and unanswered question here.

Comment: I didn't remove the downvote. Someone made an upvote for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944039/1145177

Regarding the HTML5 vs. DOCTYPE:HTML5 question, here's what I've observed while using VS 2012 RTM:

The DOCTYPE:{value} option tells VS to examine your page and attempt to figure out from the DOCTYPE and html tags what level of validation to apply. For example, if I create a page that begins as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

then the DOCTYPE:{value} option becomes DOCTYPE: HTML5. If, however, my page starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
```

then it becomes DOCTYPE: XHTML5.

The options that don't have the DOCTYPE: prefix force VS to use the selected level of validation regardless of what the structure/content of your page might suggest.